# Identificar select en javascript

Tags: javascript, select

Buenas tardes querida comunidad, estoy tratando mediante un select realizar ciertas operaciones, es decir si selecciono select1, ejecutar un alert, si se selecciona select2 una redirección. yengo el siguiente codigo funciona bien , cuando selecciono cualquier select este me devuelve el nombre del select seleccionado, yo lo que busco es identificar cual select se selecciono para poder ejecutar los procedimientos

```js
function choice1(select) {
    alert(select.options[select.selectedIndex].text);
}
```

```html
<select id="test-dropdown" onchange="choice1(this)">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

ya resolvi de la siguiente manera:

function choice1(select) {

```
    if (select.options[select.selectedIndex].text == 'Two')
    {
        alert('selecionastes Two');
        }
```

}

no se si es la forma mas practica para lo que necesito, de igual forma estaré tomando en cuenta sus sugerencias, saludos.